# Clear the search result from the pageblocktable when commandButton is clicked?

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

Apex Code:

```
public class actionSupportController 
{
    public List<PCS_Household__c> lstQuery{get;set;} 
    public List<PCS_Household__c> OnlstQuery{get;set;}
    public string ID_c{get;set;}      
    public string test{get;set;}
    public boolean out{get;set;}

    public PageReference incrementCounter() 
    {
       string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where ID=:test' ;
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        OnlstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+OnlstQuery);
        return null;
    }

     public Void doSearch()
     {
        string Query='';
        Query='SELECT ID,Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c,Previous_Dog__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%'+ID_c+'%\'';
        system.debug('==Query=='+Query);
        lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
        system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);
    }


    public pageReference doUpsert()    
    {
      out = false;
      this.OnlstQuery = '';
      return null;    
    }

}
```

VF Page:
CommanButton Name is **None of These**.

```
<apex:page controller="actionSupportController">
  <apex:form>   
    <apex:outputLabel value="Household Name:" />    
    <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}" rerender="pblck"/>                
    <apex:pageBlock id="pblck" >
      <apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstQuery}" var="eachRecord" >
        <apex:column >
          <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!incrementCounter}" rerender="out">
            <apex:param name="recordId" value="{!eachRecord.ID}" assignTo="{!test}"/>
          </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.ID}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Household__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Name}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Childrens__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Exiting_Pets__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Address__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Previous_Dog__c}"/>
      </apex:pageblockTable>
      <apex:commandButton value="None of These" onclick="this.form.reset return false;" action="{!doUpsert}" rerender="out"  />
    </apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:outputPanel id="out">
      <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!OnlstQuery}" var="eachReco">
          <!-- <apex:column value="{!eachReco.ID}"/>
<apex:column value="{!eachReco.Household__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!eachReco.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!eachReco.Phone__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!eachReco.of_Childrens__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!eachReco.of_Exiting_Pets__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!eachReco.Address__c}"/>
<apex:column value="{!eachReco.Previous_Dog__c}"/>             
<apex:column><apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.ID}"/> </apex:column> -->
          <apex:column>
            <apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.Household__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            <apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.Name}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            <apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.Phone__c}"/> 
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            <apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.of_Childrens__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            <apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.of_Exiting_Pets__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            <apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.Address__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
          <apex:column>
            <apex:inputField value="{!eachReco.Previous_Dog__c}"/>
          </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
      </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:outputPanel>           
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Edit the question and please make it more clear.

Comment: when i hit the command button i want to clear the value of page block table

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

First, setting the

```
this.OnlstQuery = '';
```

will not work, because it is a list and you try to store a String into it. Try

```
this.OnlstQuery = new List<PCS_Household__c>();
```

I think that might fix the issue.

Second, what additionally might be missing is that if you do

```
onclick="this.form.reset return false;"
```

on the button, then the `return false` will stop the button from calling the server and doing a re-render. My suggestion would be to do

```
onmouseup="this.form.reset();"
```

That's because onmouseup fires before onclick, and we will leave onclick alone, so the server is called, and the list is rerendered.

Comment: public void nullify(){
        lstQuery.clear();        
    }  this working fine

Comment: So...? Also note that you do use lstQuery and OnlstQuery which are different variables

Comment: cant able to see the first checkbox(Goods with Cats<apex:inputCheckbox /> )